# ADS Simulation: How to model an antenna in a simple rectifier circuit?

Tags: antenna, electronics, antenna-modeling

As titled, I'd like to explore the output power of a simple diode-based rectifier circuit, excited by an antenna (assumed to be 50 ohm impedance). Please give me some advice as to how to do this. It is related closely to the simulation modes, isn't it?

1/ Harmonic balance mode:

- To get the numerical values of power ( Pout= Vout * Iout): Harmonic balance is the best?
- Is it correct to model the antenna as a P_1tone as the following screenshot? Is it correct that the input power to the rectifier can be varied by varying that power source?
- Same question, with multi-band antenna. How to model it in HB mode?

2/ S parameter mode:

- To get the response in terms of S-para and Z, it is the best?
- Same question with the above questions, with 1-band and multi-band antennas? In my simulation, I simply used a 50-ohm terminal to model the 1-band antenna, but not quite sure it is correct. And I don't know how to deal with multi-band ones.

I'd highly appreciate if someone could help me in these.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to properly model an antenna in your example, you need to be very specific as to the type of antenna and its installation details. Once this is specified, the antenna can be modeled as a signal generator with a source impedance equal to the characteristic impedance of the antenna. If it is a common antenna with a typical installation, you may be able to look up the impedance. If not, you will need to model the antenna with a tool such as [EZNEC](https://www.eznec.com).

The signal level available from the receive antenna will also depend upon its irradiance due to distance, applied power, directivity, efficiency, and polarity of the transmitting antenna. These values can be applied to the [Friis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation) equation in order to resolve the maximum power available from the receive antenna when the transmit and receive antennas are within line of sight with each other.

For multi band applications you simply iterate through the above for each band involved.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, with the assumption that the input impedance of the antenna is 50 ohm, and the received power at its terminal is Pin=0dBm, is it correct if I model the antenna as P_1tone with following parameters:the parameters: P=polar(dbmtow(P_In),0), Z=50ohm? Additionally, is it okay if I use the signal generator (antenna) as V_1tone + Z1P_Eqn? Which one would be more correct?

Comment: @MinhLam You can do that but unless you require the polar feature for other reasons, you can simply specify p=dbmtow(0).

Comment: @MinhLam Regarding the correct form of the signal source, defining it as a power source keeps it in the correct context, in my opinion.